# How to publish events to graphql subscribers outside graphql server ? from messageBrokers, background jobs

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

Basically,
`pubsub.publish()` only works when it is called within the resolver.
It fails silently when called outside of it - say, in a service or `dao`, for example.

I am using `graphql-redis-subscriptions` with Redis

publish events outside `graphql` server.

I would expect to:

`import PubSub` in any file I want to push an update.

Use pubsub.publish(KEY, payload) to signal an update
subscription client should receive an update.

Am I missing something?

Using `Altaire Graphql` client, I can see the update when `pubsub.pusblish` is called in the resolver, but nothing is triggered when the same code is executed in the service - `service.add()`.